# How not to be limited by image size using an Image Handler

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler

I am converting text to image. Some of the text is longer in length than others.
**How do I make sure that none of the text is truncated?**

The code below is limiting my bitmap to 250, 30.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap imgIn = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(250, 30);
System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(imgIn);
g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
    System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

I was following this example:[How to convert Email Address or another text form TextBox to image](http://www.aspxcode.net/free-asp-net-sample-source-code.aspx?Topics=How%20to%20convert%20text%20in%20TextBox%20to%20image)

**UPDATE**

I found this article that helped accomplish my task: [Generate Image from text using C# OR Convert Text in to Image using C#](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/generate-image-from-text-using-c-or-convert-text-in-to-image-using-c/)

After I was able to resize the image according to the text length, I discovered that I need to introduce line breaks in the text otherwise the image was going all the way to Timbuktu when
the text was a couple of sentences.
**How do I introduce line breaks in long texts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66.aspx) to get the size in pixels of the text.

```
Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText("text", Font("Arial",10));
System.Drawing.Bitmap imgIn = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
```

**EDIT**

I found [this](http://www.jigar.net/howdoi/viewhtmlcontent143.aspx) article on how to write an HTTP Handler that will do what you want, it even wraps text to fit.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms does not exist in my web site.

Comment: Should I have to import System.Windows.Forms in my web site?

Comment: Yes, you will have to add a reference to the System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Comment: There is the Graphics.MeasureString, you could use this instead. Keep in mind that TextRenderer.MeasureText fixes some issues with Graphics.MeasureString, such as adding extra padding around the text. See here for more - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/magazine/cc751527.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx which is on System.Drawing.Graphics.